# Losing Materialize javascript and jquery functionality after routerLink or browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, materialize

On my home page I have a slider that is working perfectly at first but if I navigate to a different page and then return to my home page the slider loses all functionality and turns grey. This also applies to a materialboxed images where I implement a zoom in feature on my images, this feature is also lost once I start navigating through my website. for the slider I am using jquery for the functionality and for the zoom feature I am using javascript.

They work fine if I refresh the page. I also npm install jquery, for jquery dependencies instead of the cdn but it still did not work.

```
  <template>
    <div class="HomePage">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="../assets/images/Main Image.jpg">
                    <div class="caption left-align">
                        <h3 class="white-text">Welcome to HoodFave</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Shooter's win</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="../assets/images/TWIU.jpg">
                    <div class="caption  center-align">
                        <h3 class="white-text">New Collection:</h3>
                        <h5 class="light black-text text-lighten-3">"The World is Yours"</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    </div>
</template>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slider({
          full_width: false,
          interval: 7000,
          transition: 100,
          height: 750
    });
  });
```

This works fine for when I load the front page but once I navigate the website and return the slider automatically loses functionality.

Comment: Move the initiation of the slider into `mounted()` function of the component containing the slider. Vue is a SPA and you don't reload the page when you the route changes. Therefore there is only one `document.ready` when you first load the app, afterwards it won't fire again for each route change.